# news ticker with jquery

Tags: html-lists, jquery-hover

I have 1 list with the head and 1 list with the text; in automatic the header scroll and the linked text appear, and everything works.

```
function slideShow() {
  var current = $('#newsHeader li.hover');
  next = ($('#newsHeader li').index(current)<$('#newsHeader li').size()-1)? 
         current.next() :$('#newsHeader li:first'); 
  textOld = $("#newsText li:nth-child(" + (current.index() + 1) + ")"); 
  textNew = $("#newsText li:nth-child(" + (next.index() + 1) + ")");          
  current.removeClass('hover')
  next.addClass('hover')       
  textOld.removeClass('visible').fadeOut(function(){textNew.show().addClass('visible');}); 
  newsAnimation = setTimeout(slideShow, 3000);
}
```

With mouseover on the header I would like to stop the animation and see the linked text and, on mouseleave of all the box, restart the animation. I have some problem to do that, specifically I can't stop the animation queu (if I enter and leave the box a lot of time  the animation get crazy)

```
$("#newsHeader li").hover(function() {
    clearInterval(animazione);
    $('#newsHeader li.hover').removeClass('hover')              
    $( this ).addClass( "hover" );
    newNews = $("#newsText li:nth-child(" + ($(this).index() + 1) + ")");
    $('#calendario li.visible').removeClass('visible').fadeOut(function(    
        {newNews.show().addClass('visible');});     
})
$("#boxNews").mouseleave(function() {
            setTimeout(function() {slideShow()},3000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the .toogle() function. [Toogle @ jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)